# Attaching a UIView above UIKeyboard

Tags: ios

What is the most elegant way (without hardcoding pixel numbers) to attach UIView right above UIKeyboard.

Use case: I have a use case where when user wants to type anything, I want to allow him share the content on twitter and facebook. I have a UIView which has buttons to share on facebook and twitter.

I want that UIView to 
1. appear only when UIKeyboard is visible
2. appear right above UIKeyboard. Even when device is rotated.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [inputAccessoryView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputAccessoryView) on the various text input fields.